# json.loads with backslash quote breaks

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to json.load the following string

```
json.loads('''{"summary": "win32k.sys in the kernel-mode drivers in Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP2, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 SP2 and R2 SP1, Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 Gold and R2, and Windows RT Gold and 8.1 allows local users to gain privileges or cause a denial of service (NULL pointer dereference) via a crafted application, aka \"Win32k Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability.\"", "update_date": "2015-02-18T22: 00: 10", "version": 1}''')
```

But it struggles each time at the `\"`. Is there an easy way to properly escape this value so json.loads understand it?

Answer (score 3):

Use  raw string `r`:

```
json.loads(r'''{"summary": "win32k.sys in the kernel-mode drivers in Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP2, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 SP2 and R2 SP1, Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 Gold and R2, and Windows RT Gold and 8.1 allows local users to gain privileges or cause a denial of service (NULL pointer dereference) via a crafted application, aka \"Win32k Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability.\"", "update_date": "2015-02-18T22: 00: 10", "version": 1}''')

js = json.loads(r'''{"summary": "win32k.sys in the kernel-mode drivers in Microsoft Windows Server 2003 SP2, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 SP2 and R2 SP1, Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 Gold and R2, and Windows RT Gold and 8.1 allows local users to gain privileges or cause a denial of service (NULL pointer dereference) via a crafted application, aka \"Win32k Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability.\"", "update_date": "2015-02-18T22: 00: 10", "version": 1}''')
print(js)
```

Comment: Although if they are entering the JSON as a literal string anyway, I don't understand why they don't just write it as a literal dict in the first place.